# Getting Typescript error: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. TS2345

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. `Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.  TS2345` Here is my code. It's complaining about the merged array.

```
  const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const validatorResponse = await axios.get(validatorEndpoint);
      const validatorIps = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < validatorResponse.data.count; i += 1) {
        const ipAddress = validatorResponse.data.results[i].ip_address;
        validatorIps.push({query: ipAddress});
      }
      const resultBatch = await axios.post(ipInfoEndpoint, validatorIps);
      const merged = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < validatorResponse.data.results.length; i += 1) {
        merged.push({
          ...validatorResponse.data.results[i],
          ...resultBatch.data[i],
        });
      }
      console.log(merged);
      setAllInfo(merged);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This is the line returning the error -

```
setAllInfo(merged);
```

I've tried

```
const result : string[] = [];
```

As well as const

```
[allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState([] as any);
```

Comment: Have you tried `const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState<any[]>([]);`?

Comment: @JayKariesch Just tried that and got 
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: You say it's complaining about the merged array, do you mean when you try to set the merged array to state, or a different line of code?

Comment: @CoryHarper Yes when I try to setAllInfo(merged); That is the line returning the error

Comment: What are the types for `validatorResponse.data.results[i]` and `resultBatch.data[i]`? If any of those are `never`, the result expressions force `merged` to be `never[]`.

Comment: try `const merged: any[] = []` along with `const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState<any[]>([]);`

Comment: However, I would suggest if you are using Typescript, that you create an interface for what the shape of those objects you get as a response should look like.

Comment: @CoryHarper No, that did not work. I get same error. 

Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.  TS2345

Comment: @CoryHarper I'm new to TypeScript (and React for that matter). This was the only way I could figure out how to get it working how I wanted it. I was developing with "strict" set to false and then when I turned it to true, I started getting this problem.

Comment: I think we should start there. Create an interface that at least loosely resembles your API response, then instantiate your state like `const [state, setState] = useState<APIResponse[]>([])`. That would be a pretty typical React pattern.

Comment: That interface can then also be used with `merged`

Comment: Here's a good place to start about interfaces: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: @CoryHarper Thanks, I got it working with an interface and also used the  Array.prototype.map method suggested by @ Omri Luzon. If you want to leave an answer, I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your state an interface to strictly type it is a common pattern when using Typescript and React, otherwise the Typescript compiler will infer it. While with many other types inference will work, with an array most of the time it won't because the safest type to assume for an empty array is `never[]`.

All of that to say that when you are creating an array that is assigned to a variable it is best to type that array strictly using an interface or custom type.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

So your code will often look more like this:

```
interface Foo {
  ...
}
...

const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState<Foo[]>([]);

const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const { 
    data: {
     results = []
    } = {} 
  } = await axios.get(validatorEndpoint);
  const validatorIps = results.map(({ ip_address }) => ({query: id_address}));
  const { data = [] } = await axios.post(ipInfoEndpoint, validatorIps);

  const merged = results.map((result, i) => ({
    ...result,
    ...data[i]
  });

 setAllInfo(merged)
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

I typed that using what information I had, but in the future you should also give types to your API responses inside of `fetchData` or you'll run into more type issues by relying on inference.

One last thing, `fetchData` inside of the `useEffect` is violating `exhaustive-deps` linter rule React has. It isn't hugely problematic in this case, but `fetchData` should really be defined inside the `useEffect` or with the `useCallback` hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the error be giving `merged` a better type than the inferred one (`never[]`).

`const merged: any[] = [];` should be enough, but I would recommend you consider a better type.

You can also help typescript infer the type by using the `Array.prototype.map` method, and it's generally better to use `.map` when you want to create new array with every element transformed from the original array.

```js
const merged = validatorResponse.data.results.map((result, i) => ({
   ...result,
   ...resultBatch.data[i],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use default values this prevent future TypeError, try to use real typed, not use any like type

```
const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState<Array<typed>>([]);

const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const { 
    data: {
     results = []
    } = {} 
  } = await axios.get(validatorEndpoint);
  const validatorIps = results.map(({ ip_address}) => ({query: id_address}));

  const { data = []}= await axios.post(ipInfoEndpoint, validatorIps);
  const merged = results.map((result, i) => ({
    ...result,
    ...data[i]
  });
 setAllInfo(merged)
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

`